# Why install node js version 8.xx but still show version v6.3.1?

Tags: node.js, linux, centos, centos7

My server is centos 7

I was install node js 8.x with this command line

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -
```

and

```
sudo yum -y install nodejs
```

When finished i will check version by `node -v` but still show `v6.3.1`

How can i do ?

Comment: did you try to reboot the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (Node Version Manager) to manage your node versions. It's very useful and it's a great tool to manage your node versions.

---

**To install NVM, run this script on your console:**

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

Then, to download the latest release of node the following two commands:

```
nvm install node
nvm use node
```

If you want to install a specific version of node, you can simply run:

```
nvm install v8.9.0
nvm use v8.9.0
```

I hope this helped, if you're still having trouble please let me know.